# Why did Clear() clear both DataTables?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datatable

In my winform program (in vb.net) I wrote:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
'Get data from DB into dt
'...

Dim dttemp As New DataTable
dttemp = dt
dt.Clear()
'...
```

But when I run the program, `Clear()` cleared both `dt` and `dttemp`! 
Why? Aren't `dt` and `dttemp` supposed to be two distinct instances of `DataTable`?

(I finally found a solution - `dttemp = dt.Copy()` instead of `dttemp = dt`. But I still can't see why `Copy()` was necessary in this case. Sorry if it's a basic question - I'm a beginner programmer.)

Comment: "dttemp = dt" assigned your temp variable to the same instance as your main "dt" so they both held the same reference to the same object. Make more sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `DataTable` is a *reference type*.

The values of `dttemp` and `dt` are just references to the same object.

If I write my address down on a piece of paper and give it to two people, then one of them burgles me (clears my house/DataTable) then if the second person visits me they'll find the house empty. That's what's happening here.

I have an article (C#-based, but the same applies) about [reference types and value types](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html) which you may find useful.

Comment: Nice analogy. So `Copy()` would be equivalent to building another house, identical to the first one, but down the street? And then the buglers would be given two different addresses. Right?

Comment: @kodkod: Not necessarily in the same place at all - but yes, it would build another house with a copy of the same things in. So if the burglars stole from one house, the copy would remain intact.

Answer (score 4):

When you write `dttemp = dt`, you're changing `dttemp` to refer to the same `DataTable` instance as `dt`.

It doesn't create a separate copy of the instance.

Value types (structs) behave the way you're expecting, but reference types (classes) do not.

Answer (score 0):

```
You should do:

Dim dt As New DataTable
'Get data from DB into dt
'...

Dim dttemp As New DataTable
dttemp = dt.Copty()
dt.Clear()
'...
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you do `variable = New Something` you are creating an instance of that class, and setting up a **reference** that points to that particular instance.

So, in your code `dt` and `dttemp` are just references to a DataTable object.

So what your code does is:

1. Create a new `DataTable` object, and set the `dt` reference to point to it
2. Create another `DataTable` object, and set the `dttemp` reference to point to it
3. **Set the `dttemp` reference to point to whatever `dt` is referencing** (in this case the first data table). This effectively orphans the second data table, and makes it eligible for garbage collection.

So, since both `dt` and `dttemp` are referencing the same object, whatever is done via the one, will be visible via the second.
When you are doing `dt.Copy()` you are creating another instance of the DataTable class, copying the values from the first to the second datatable, and returning the second.
That way you have two separate instances, that you can manage as you wish.